How to change the order of items in a Stack without disposing the instances?
I am trying to make a main page that is built in a Stack inside which there are a number of animated widgets that when tapped dragged or panned slide in and out of the View. I will add a video to make it clear. An issue I am facing however is that when these widgets come in and out of view since they are all inside a stack one appears partly on top of another. I have tried setting the order of the stack or adding a new list of widgets that have the updated order of widgets before, but it disposes of the widgets while the ticker is still active for the animation. What approach can I use to solve this issue? a good analogue of this problem is in CSS where u can set the z indexes but I cant find something similar in flutter.
Here is my build function:
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bottomTaskBar ??= SizedBox(
        width: 100.safeAreaW(context),
        height: 100.safeAreaH(context),
        child: SliderWithTextFieldWidget(),
      );
    leftMenuSliderWidget ??= SlideWidget();
    topDragDownWidget ??= SlideWidget();

    stackChildren[0] = topDragDownWidget!;
    stackChildren[1] = Positioned(
          top: 0,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 100.safeAreaW(context),
            height: 100.safeAreaH(context),
            child: Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const  EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70.0),
                child: ClockWidget(
                  width: 60.sw(context),
                  workDuration: const Duration(minutes: 25),
                  breakDuration:const Duration(minutes: 5),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
    stackChildren[2] = Positioned(
          right: 0,
          top: 0,
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, right: 10),
            child:  SlideWidget(
              threshold: 40,
              position: Position.right,
              width: 60,
              openLength: 190 ,
              closedLength:  60,
              content: Container(
                color: Colors.deepPurple,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
    stackChildren[3] = leftMenuSliderWidget!;
    stackChildren[4] = bottomTaskBar!;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.devicePaddingTop(context),bottom: 100.devicePaddingBottom(context)),
          child: Stack(
            children: stackChildren
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

Here is the gif of the current behavior:
current behavior
As you can see the widget from the left is behind the bottom widget. I would like to make it so that depending on which one is being opened it changes position in the stack

Hey good to see you here i am going through the question but i am unable to visualise the issue can you please share the expected behaviour as gif so able to help you.

It is already added to the post please see the gif of the current behavior

The issue is each time Stack is rebuild, the old SlideWidget is lost.
You can use GlobalKey (create them in State not build) to preserve state between builds. And sort the children to determine their order.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final Map<Color, int> rank = {
    Colors.red: 1,
    Colors.blue: 2,
    Colors.green: 3,
    Colors.yellow: 4,
  };
  final Map<Color, GlobalKey> keys = {
    Colors.red: GlobalKey(),
    Colors.blue: GlobalKey(),
    Colors.green: GlobalKey(),
    Colors.yellow: GlobalKey(),
  };
  final Map<Color, EdgeInsets> padding = {
    Colors.red: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, left: 100),
    Colors.blue: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, right: 100),
    Colors.green: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100, left: 100),
    Colors.yellow: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100, right: 100),
  };

  int nextRank = 5;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final rankedColors = rank.keys.toList()..sort((a, b) => rank[a]!.compareTo(rank[b]!));
    return Stack(
      children: [
        for (final color in rankedColors)
          Padding(
            padding: padding[color]!,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  rank[color] = nextRank;
                  nextRank += 1;
                });
              },
              child: MyTimer(
                key: keys[color],
                color: color,
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyTimer extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color color;
  const MyTimer({super.key, required this.color});

  @override
  State<MyTimer> createState() => _MyTimerState();
}

class _MyTimerState extends State<MyTimer> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController controller = AnimationController(
    upperBound: 1000,
    duration: const Duration(minutes: 10),
    vsync: this,
  )..forward();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: widget.color,
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: controller,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(controller.value.toStringAsFixed(3)),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}

